# python + apache + csv file

Tags: python, html, apache, csv

I am trying to access a `csv` file through `python` in `apache2`. It is giving an internal server error. I don't see the actual error in `error.log` file.

If I run the `python` file in command line without `apache2`, it works fine and I can access the `csv` file to display `html` page in browser. Any idea what could be the error?

Thanks guys!   My Python project is in Apache htdocs. Apache runs my Python file as usual and everything works perfectly, eg: PostgreSQL.   CSV file is in static folder of my Python project.   For example:  Project:  Server.py

```
app.route('/access_page') 
def page():      
Open with ('static\\file.csv', 'r') as inFile: 



reader = csv.reader(inFile)
```

`File  = [row for row in reader]`
`return render_template('access_page.html', File = File)`
Read function: 
`def readFile(aFile):`
 `with open(aFile , 'r') as inFile:'`
reader = csv.reader(inFile)
anyFile = [row for row in reader]
return anyFile`
Flask template in html page:

```
 <table> {% for line in File %} <tr> {% for item in line%} <td> {{item}} </td> {% endfor %} </tr> {% endfor %} </table>
```

Comment: Can you show some code? How exactly are you using apache and python?

Comment: Where is the .csv file stored? It may be in a location that is accessible to your userid, but not to the apache userid.

Comment: You can probably tail the syslog and see some exceptions

Comment: Hi guys, I tried everything.. No luck! Is it possible to look again  the description above ? Thanks